# What methods are there for estimating distributions based on histograms?

Tags: density-function, histogram, weibull-distribution, density-estimation

I recently worked on a consulting project where a client wanted to estimate gamma and weibull distributions based purely on histograms rather than raw-data. I have never worked with problems like that before, so if there are references (Books/articles) that people can point me to, that would be awesome.

Comment: Provided the histogram bins were predetermined (and not based on the data, as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919), maximum likelihood works well and is easy to apply.  See examples at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34894/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/56100/919, for instance. These presume your histograms depict univariate datasets and not, for instance, data in some kind of regression problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that. We were looking at MLE-based methods to estimate and compare 2-parameter and 3-parameter weibull distributions using right-endpoints in histograms to measure wave heights, and we were struggling a bit.

Comment: Is the client saying the data aren't available? Or that the data are available but they believe the histogram is somehow superior to something that can be calculated from the full data/

Comment: Exactly - the data aren't available. They had some in-house data, but when they wanted to work with data from other agencies, the best they could work with was histograms from reports/publications.